# Configuring JDK, SDK with Android Studio and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio

First,

- I installed `jdk-7u80-windows-x64` from Oracle,
- after that I install android studio along with SDK(I don't know what version) and they run smoothly.

Second,

- I opened eclipse because I have installed `jdk-7u80-windows-x64` but there's a message that I must have JDK or JRE (in my opinion maybe eclipse doesn't recognize the first JDK) so,
- I installed `jdk-6u16-windows-i586`(so my laptop has two JDK's).

go on, I open eclipse and configure with ADT (finish) and configure with SDK but things going wrong there should be some in the list I click on the SDK folder but there is nothing in the list

[image: Eclipse_Workspace_Window_screenshot]

Comment: Hey folks, please note that eclipse and android development are going separate ways, at least in the near future. The officially supported IDE is Android Studio.

Comment: well i have Android studio too but i don't have it's ebook, but i have eclipse for developing android ebook. that's right now i'm doing. well thanks your information great help but if only you have ebook for android studio it will be great help

Comment: sorry, I don't have that

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to have more than one JDK / JRE installed on the same PC.

To solve your problem, I think you have to configure your JRE in Eclipse:

1. Go to `Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JRE's`
2. Go to `Add... -> Standard JVM -> Directory... ->`. Search for your JDK root directory and click Ok (JDK libraries will be charged in the JRE System libraries)
3. Check the JDK you added, Click `Finish` and `Apply` all changes to the Preferences.
4. Restart Eclipse

If you follow this you will see the configured JREs as shown in the below image will resolve your problem.

[image]